# Codeigniter Shopping Cart Helper Class - Change the "subtotal" value

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I am working with the CI Framework and using the Shopping Cart Class. Which has proved a success so far, Until my user has decided to mess about with it and add postage to the total.

So what I'd like to do is add the value of the variable $postage to the subtotal array.

i.e subtotal is first 111.24, Then it goes to my controller and it adds 4 to the subtotal making it 115.24.

My array of data is as follows :

```
[id] => 9
        [qty] => 1
        [price] => 111.24
        [price_artwork] => 
        [name] => Lincoln Catherdral
        [print_type] => Canvas
        [postage] => 4
        [file_name] => bbb5359bd6d0dc27ace3f2921460a021
        [file_ext] => .jpg
        [subtotal] => 111.24
```

and $data in the controller is set as follows:

```
$data = array(
           'id'             => $this->input->post('ARTWORK_id'),
           'qty'            => 1,
           'price'          => $this->input->post('print_cost'),
           'price_artwork'  => $this->input->post('ARTWORK_price'),
           'name'           => $this->input->post('ARTWORK_title'),
           'print_type'     => $this->input->post('print_type'),
           'postage'        => $postage,
           'file_name'      => $this->input->post('ARTWORK_file_name'),
           'file_ext'       => $this->input->post('ARTWORK_file_ext'),
           'subtotal'       => $subtotal
        );
```

But subtotal is only going through as the same as the [price] value in the array.

Any ideas how to change this?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't add postage to 'subtotal' your subtotal should only include itemxcost, not sum of everything + shipping. Calculate the postage on top of the subtotal IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I would try this and see if it works:

Change:

```
       'subtotal'       => $subtotal
```

To:

```
       'subtotal'       => $this->input->post('print_cost') + $postage
```

**Or**, before the array is set, add this line:

```
$subtotal += $postage;
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for that answer. It appears that you cant seem to do much with that "subtotal" element of the array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? It looks like your problem is that `$subtotal` isn't incorporating `$postage`, which is why I suggested to add that value to `$subtotal`. It didn't work?

Comment: Unfortunatley not. It appears that subtotal is declared in the CI session data, Rather than overwriting it in the array. Removing the subtotal bit from the array, Still gives you the array data with [subtotal] in it.

Comment: You are most likely not looking at the correct code then - You'll have to figure out where the subtotal value is coming from in order to change it

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a CodeIgniter question and more of a PHP question, assuming I've grasped what you're after correctly.

The issue is that `$subtotal` is wrong.  This isn't the class changing the value, it's just wrong in the first place.

By the sounds of it you're just trying to add the price with the postage?  This should be very simple:
`$subtotal = $this->input->post('print_cost') + $this->input->post('ARTWORK_price') + $postage;`

Failing that, do some simple debugging; print out the `$subtotal` field before declaring the array.

Comment: Hi @mikemike I believe it is a CI question. Removing subtotal from the array, It is still written by what seems like the CI Shopping Cart class

Comment: I'm confused on the issue here.  If you're setting $subtotal and it's coming out wrong, then the value you're setting it to is incorrect, surely?

Comment: I have solved the problem by going into the CI Shopping Cart Class and overwriting it in my controller.